Python how to fit value, weight using different distributions
I have tabular data in form of values, weight and would like to fit different distributions like normal, lognormal, etc. and get sum squared error of fitting. I tried normal distribution so far using scipy.stats.norm.fit() but it does not give any indication of error. Is there built-in way in python to fit weighted data and get sum squared error? Looks like fitter library can fit different distributions and get an error indication, but it doesn't work on weighted distributions.
My data looks like
value,weight
11.12,0.001
12.112,0.05
...

For example, value 11.12 occurs 0.1% in the total data.

I don't think you'd want sum of squared error. When fitting a distribution to a set of data, the distribution does not predict any specific values. It only gives a probability for each value. The log likelyhood would probably be more useful.

Have you tried scipy.stats.fit()? This gives you a result object that you can call nllf() on to get a measure of the negative log-likehood function for that distribution and data.

What is the meaning of your weights?

Are your data some king of histogram? Because you talk about distributions and squared error of fitting at the same time I can assume this.

import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate sample data
data = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=1000)

# Visualize the data
plt.hist(data, bins=30, density=True)
plt.show()

# Check for normality
stat, p = stats.shapiro(data)
print("Shapiro-Wilk test:", stat, p)

# Check for exponential distribution
stat, p = stats.kstest(data, 'expon')
print("Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (exponential):", stat, p)

# Fit a normal distribution
dist = stats.norm.fit(data)
print("Fitted normal distribution:", dist)

# Generate sample data
data = np.random.lognormal(mean=0, sigma=1, size=1000)

# Visualize on a log scale
plt.hist(np.log(data), bins=30, density=True)
plt.show()

# Check for lognormality
stat, p = stats.shapiro(np.log(data))
print("Shapiro-Wilk test (lognormal):", stat, p)

# Fit a lognormal distribution
dist = stats.lognorm.fit(data)
print("Fitted lognormal distribution:", dist)

